# What is the overhead for the Redis index?

Tags: indexing, redis, overhead, redis-search

According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1dFmF3IJOI&t=3s  minute 3:25, 2TB in Flash requires 75GB overhead in RAM. This means the 75GB only holds the index and not the data. The data are small blocks of 500B or less.

How can we calculate the overhead for the Redis index or Redis Search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FT.INFO` command to get size and other information about your index:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.INFO idx
1) index_name
 2) wikipedia
 3) index_options
 4) (empty array)
    11) score_field
    12) __score
    13) payload_field
    14) __payload
 7) fields
 8) 1) 1) title
       2) type
       3) TEXT
       4) WEIGHT
       5) "1"
       6) SORTABLE
    2) 1) body
       2) type
       3) TEXT
       4) WEIGHT
       5) "1"
    3) 1) id
       2) type
       3) NUMERIC
    4) 1) subject location
       2) type
       3) GEO
 9) num_docs
10) "0"
11) max_doc_id
12) "345678"
13) num_terms
14) "691356"
15) num_records
16) "0"
17) inverted_sz_mb
18) "0"
19) vector_index_sz_mb
20) "0"
21) total_inverted_index_blocks
22) "933290"
23) offset_vectors_sz_mb
24) "0.65932846069335938"
25) doc_table_size_mb
26) "29.893482208251953"
27) sortable_values_size_mb
28) "11.432285308837891"
29) key_table_size_mb
30) "1.239776611328125e-05"
31) records_per_doc_avg
32) "-nan"
33) bytes_per_record_avg
34) "-nan"
35) offsets_per_term_avg
36) "inf"
37) offset_bits_per_record_avg
38) "8"
39) hash_indexing_failures
40) "0"
41) indexing
42) "0"
43) percent_indexed
44) "1"
45) number_of_uses
46) 1
47) gc_stats
48)  1) bytes_collected
     2) "4148136"
     3) total_ms_run
     4) "14796"
     5) total_cycles
     6) "1"
     7) average_cycle_time_ms
     8) "14796"
     9) last_run_time_ms
    10) "14796"
    11) gc_numeric_trees_missed
    12) "0"
    13) gc_blocks_denied
    14) "0"
49) cursor_stats
50) 1) global_idle
    2) (integer) 0
    3) global_total
    4) (integer) 0
    5) index_capacity
    6) (integer) 128
    7) index_total
    8) (integer) 0
51) stopwords_list
52) 1) "tlv"
    2) "summer"
    3) "2020"
```

Ref: https://redis.io/commands/ft.info/